# Mysql How to grant permissions to a specific table that exists in multiple databases?

Tags: mysql

I need grant permissions to a user to allow him to get access to a table that exists in the different databases without having to create different grants manually for each database. As a simple example the DBS and tables are like the example below:

```
databaseone.fruits
databasetwo.fruits
databasethree.fruits
```

I´m trying this command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `database%`.fruits TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I get an error saying that the table doesn't exist.

There is any way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: use 3 seperate commands. Afterall how are you expecting to make use of the `%` in that DDL command

Comment: Create a role. Grant permissions to this tables (3 separate queries) to it. Assign this role to the user. If the table with this name occures in anotheк database in future then do not forget to grant the permissions to this new table to the role.

Comment: It has to be dynamic, the databases above are just an example, I have more than 100 databases, so I cant manually create it